# How to execute the 2 sql queries through python program

Tags: python, sqlite

How can we execute 2 sql queries in python program which would access the sqlite database.?
Here I can only execute the first query but not the second one.?

```
import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect("suman1.db")

cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor

cursor.execute("select Album.AlbumId,Album.Title,Track.Name,Track.GenreId,Track.UnitPrice from Album inner join Track on Album.AlbumId=Track.AlbumId")

cursor.execute("select Track.TrackId,Album.Title,Track.Name,Track.Unitprice,Track.Bytes from Album inner join Track on Album.AlbumId=Track.AlbumId where UnitPrice=1.99 and Title like '%Season 4%'and GenreId like '%21%'")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
   print row

conn.commit()          
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Both queries are executed.

The problem is that you never read the results of the first query.
(Executing another query resets the cursor.)

You have to read the results before you execute the next query:

```
cursor.execute("select ...")

for row in cursor:
    print row

cursor.execute("select ...")

for row in cursor:
    print row
```

or use two cursors.